# Step vs. comparison operator in HLSL?

Tags: hlsl, intrinsics

As an HLSL enthusiast, I've been in the habit of using (float)(x>=y).  Usually for 0/1 multiplications for branch avoidance.  I just revisited my intrinsic list and saw step(x,y).  They sound equivalent in output to me.

Are there any reasons to prefer one of these styles over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they're equivalent. This shader:

```
inline float test1( float x, float y )
{
    return (float)( x >= y );
}

inline float test2( float x, float y )
{
    return step( x, y );
}

float2 main(float4 c: COLOR0): SV_Target
{
    float2 res;
    res.x =  test1( c.x, c.y );
    res.y =  test2( c.z, c.w );
    return res;
}
```

Compiles into following DXBC instructions:

```
ps_4_0
dcl_input_ps linear v0.xyzw
dcl_output o0.xy
dcl_temps 1
ge r0.xy, v0.xwxx, v0.yzyy   // If the comparison is true, then 0xFFFFFFFF is returned for that component.
and o0.xy, r0.xyxx, l(0x3f800000, 0x3f800000, 0, 0)   // Component-wise logical AND, 0x3f800000 = 1.0f
ret
```

As you see, the compiler treated both inline functions as equivalents, it even merged then together into a single 2-lane vector comparison.

Comment: Be careful that step( x, y ) is equivalent to x < y, so test1() and test2() will return opposite values!

Comment: @Patapom no it's not 
> This function uses the following formula: (x >= y) ? 1 : 0. The function returns either 0 or 1 depending on whether the x parameter is greater than the y parameter.

from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-step

Comment: Check the order of the parameters, x is the second parameter...